# Testing CLI arguments in go

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, automated-tests, command-line-interface

I want to test some CLI routines in go that are run in the main() function purely, they are just exercises that I'm doing, but I want to make tests on them!
So for example how can I pass arguments to table test this king of algorithm?

```
package main


import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var f *os.File
    f = os.Stdin
    defer f.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        if scanner.Text() == "STOP" || scanner.Text() == "stop" {
            break
        }

        n, err := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("Number formatted: %d\n", n)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

I put the code on playground too for better help!
https://play.golang.org/p/JgrQ2yFogNs

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't test it very well as it is right now, but it's easy enough to extract a function that is trivially testable: https://play.golang.org/p/d9pE75_uULQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function which input and output channels as params. It should  read and write to these params. Following is an example:

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    var f *os.File
    f = os.Stdin
    defer f.Close()
    run (os.Stdin, f)
}

func run(in io.Reader, out io.Writer) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(in)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        if scanner.Text() == "STOP" || scanner.Text() == "stop" {
            break
        }

        n, err := strconv.ParseInt(scanner.Text(), 10, 64)

        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("Number formatted: %d\n", n)
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

main_test.go

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)
func TestRun(t *testing.T){
    var command, result bytes.Buffer
    fmt.Fprintf(&command, "10\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(&command, "stop\n")
    run(&command, &result)
    got := result.String()
    //test for contents of "got"
    fmt.Println(got)
}
```

Now you can run the following on a command line.

```
go test
```

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, you don't need to use Go for this. When I'm looking at writing a CLI tool I break out of `main` as soon as possible with functions and structs the unit test those in the usual way.

To make sure that all the CLI arguments and file system buts are plumbed in correctly I've been using https://github.com/bats-core/bats-core to run the command and check the fully built tool.

You can see an example of how I've done this at https://github.com/dnnrly/abbreviate

Perhaps not the answer you're looking for but it's been working well for me.